# How do I give student score that are equal same rank

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-entities

This is the code I currently have which is working just that when the students score are the same they get different ranks which is not what I would like

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        using (var db = new SchoolEntities())
        {
            int rank= 0;
            var query = db.ScoreSummaries
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalScore).ToList();

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                rank+= 1;
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", item.TransactionID, item.TotalScore, rank);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Pls press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

My result is as follows, notice that the first two records are the same but have different ranks. I would like both records to have a rank of 1 and the next one a rank of 3. Any suggestion would be appreciated

```
TRANS01,92,1
TRANS01,92,2
TRANS01,88,3
TRANS01,85,4
TRANS01,79,5
Pls press any key to exit
```

Comment: Have a container of ranks, and add those with the same score to that container. If that container doesn't exist yet, make another container with the appropriate rank and add that score to it.

Comment: There are several conventions for assigning ranks when you have duplicates. Competition rank tired elements given rank of lowest 4,2,2,1. This is Excel's standards, dense ranking 3,2,2,1, Ordinal ranking each has a unique value: 4,3,2,1 and Fractional ranking, mean of ordinal ranks of tied elements 4,2.5,2.5,1.

Comment: @Salixalba, this is quite educative about rankings.I really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i would do it is. save your current score to new variable

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        using (var 

db = new SchoolEntities())
        {
            double currentScore = 0;
            int rank= 0;
            int savedRank;
        var query = db.ScoreSummaries
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalScore).ToList();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {

      rank+= 1;
      if(item.TotalScore == current score)
       {
        savedRank = savedRank
       }
       else
       {
         savedrank = rank;
        }

            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", item.TransactionID, item.TotalScore, savedrank);
            currentScore = item.totalScore;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Pls press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd try this out but note that TotalScore is of type double

Comment: @presssharp Ok i just changed it should work the same. Let me know if there is any holes in the idea. I also think rank +=1 should be above the if now that i look at it again.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
        int rank= 0;
        int lastScore = 0;
        var query = db.ScoreSummaries
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalScore).ToList();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            if (lastScore > item.TotalScore)
                rank++;

            lastScore = item.TotalScore;
            Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}", item.TransactionID, item.TotalScore, rank);
        }
```

Comment: thanks, I already tried this out works for dense ranking as stated above by @Salix alba but still not for competition rank!

Comment: They maybe try to add another variable, such as rankCounter, and increment that if the rank is not incremented (in an else under rank++).    Then add that rankCounter to the rank where I incremented it in my code, then reset rankCounter back to 0.    if (lastScore > item.TotalScore){
                rank += rankCounter;
    rankCounter = 0;
}
else {
 rankCounter++;
}

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that this is an assignment for some class.

You are trying to keep track of the current rank of a student, along with the total number of students that you have gone through. To do this, you'll need to keep track of each in their own variable, and modify them at the appropriate times.

The number of students that you've gone through can be incremented each time, like your rank variable currently is; the current_rank variable will need to be incremented separately from that (maybe based on the previous student's grade, hint, hint).

Comment: Well! this is not an assignment. Thanks for the suggestion though